# /users/{userId} is only available for current user?

Tags: ldap, settings, clockify

I use the `Clockify API` to sync objects to and from our other databases.

I try to update the user image from our `LDAP` user repo; works fine on my own account, but when I try to update the image for someone else I get a `403`.

That leads me to the conclusion that everything under `/users` is only available for the current user (even if the current user is admin of the workspace). If so, can that be clarified in the documentation?

https://clockify.github.io/clockify_api_docs/#tag-User

Is there a way to update user `settings/profile` for someone else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right. By design, you can't edit other people's User Settings.

This is because the person in your workspace might have other workspaces (be it their own or someone else's). You're only someone's admin in your particular workspace, and they're free to have other workspaces beside yours.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are right, I can't GET users/{userId} except for my own user ID. Attempting to get it for other user IDs, even those users on my team and I'm the owner/admin, gives the 403 Forbidden.

I would recommend reaching out to support@clockify.me, they may be able to fix it - or at least they can be made aware of the issue. I've had success in contacting them and they respond relatively quickly.

Comment: I am not sure if this is an issue. I think it is intentional and not a bug. But if so, then the documentation needs clarification imho.

Comment: I agree - but it still never hurts to reach out to them directly, they may update the documentation, or fix it. I'm not sure they monitor this all that much to see it here.

Comment: According to their statement on the docs github repo, they do.

https://github.com/clockify/clockify_api_docs

Comment: I've send them a mail,I'll update the question when I have an answer.